# Swap column value of same table in single SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have requirement to update column value of two rows with different keys. Constraint is that i want to do this in single query.

For example:

```
Coll1   Coll2
---------------
  A       1
  B       2
  C       3
```

Should be like

```
Coll1   Coll2
--------------
  A       3
  B       2
  C       1
```

Comment: SqlZim is right, but why do you have do it in a single query?

Comment: More appropriate word would be 'single transaction'.

Comment: I just added a generic solution, without hard coding any value

Answer (score 6):

using a `case` expression:

```
update t
  set Coll2 = case when Coll1 = 'A' then 3 else 1 end
where Coll1 in ('A','C')
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HUBDAP9516

returns:

```
+-------+-------+
| Coll1 | Coll2 |
+-------+-------+
| A     |     3 |
| B     |     2 |
| C     |     1 |
+-------+-------+
```

---

update for a parameterized version:

```
declare @key1 char(1) = 'A';
declare @key2 char(1) = 'C';
update t
  set t.Coll2 =  x.Coll2
from t
  inner join t x
    on t.Coll1 <> x.Coll1
   and t.Coll1 in (@key1,@key2)
   and x.Coll1 in (@key1,@key2)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PKQSAV63963

returns:

```
+-------+-------+
| Coll1 | Coll2 |
+-------+-------+
| A     |     3 |
| B     |     2 |
| C     |     1 |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Dang it, beat me to it haha

Comment: Ah even a demo! :P

Comment: Would you take a look at my proposed solution?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you mean a single transaction. Either way, I don't understand why--but since that is what you want, here's an easy way.

```
declare @table table (Col1 char(1), Col2 int)
insert into @table
values
('A',1),
('B',2),
('C',3)

update @table
set 
    Col2 = case
                when Col1 = 'A' then 3
                when Col1 = 'C' then 1
            end
where Col1 in ('A','C')

select * from @table
```

Comment: That's fair @xQbert :D

Comment: <Monty Python> C sire.  Not B.  </Monty Python>

Comment: IMHO, both answers are not satisfactory in that you hard-code the col2 value (i.e 1, 3). To me, an acceptable answer should be I know the value of col1 (i.e. A or C) and then I need to swap the value of col2 for the two rows (i.e. col1 = A or C)

Comment: @jyao judging by [your profile](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlserverauthor/121/jeffrey-yao/) I think you'd also agree the original question was pretty ridiculous, hence the simplistic answers. There's no real reason to have this in a single "query" and the sample data was far too simplified to guess at a any logical reasoning or better way to handle this.

Comment: Haha.. @scsimon, agree with your comment, but I'd say the question is fun in some perspective..

Comment: Would you take a look at my proposed solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE t SET Coll2 = 3 WHERE Coll1 = 'A'
UPDATE t SET Coll2 = 1 WHERE Coll1 = 'C'
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to try the following answer without hard-code col2

```
create table #t (col1 char(301), col2 int);
go
insert into #t (col1, col2)
values ('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)

; with c as (
select col1, col2
from #t
)
update t
set t.col2 = c.col2
from #t t
inner join c
on abs(ascii(t.col1) - ascii(c.col1))=2


select * from #t
```

Comment: Would you take a look at my proposed solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic solution where you have values to switch as a parameter or as a subquery.

It also works con char data, but need some tweaking on string manipulation.

```
declare @table table (Col1 char(1), Col2 int)
insert into @table
values
('A',1),
('B',2),
('C',3)


declare @swap1 char='A'
declare @swap2 char='C'   

update @table
set col2 = (select sum(col2) from @table
    where col1 in (@swap1,@swap2))-col2
where col1 in (@swap1,@swap2)
```

Comment: While you did parameterize the query, it would be better to parameterize the case statement in mine and SQLZim's solution. Then, it would handle non-numerical data. Plus, you have introduced an aggregation which is necessary. It is a different and clever method, but is less performant. Abstract thinking though--good job

Comment: @scsimon thanks. IMO the problem is not hard coding search text but the values in both answers. Could you both do it in one sentence as OP requested?

Comment: @Horaciux, your solution is a very nice one to the table in question with its data as it is (i.e. col2 is int).